# Set SP list column visibility in Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I have a column called "Approver" in SP's list and I want to make it only visible to a limited number of people by their Email addresses. I made a custom form in Power Apps and tried to set it "visible" as

```
if(User().FullName="user@email.com";true;false)
```

But it doesn't work. I guess I'm missing something.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: did you check what comes under User().FulName? make sure you are comparing the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula like below:

```
If(User().Email = "user@email.com", true, false)
```

**OR**:

```
User().Email = "user@email.com"
```

---

**For multiple users**:

```
User().Email = "abc@email.com" || User().Email = "xyz@email.com" || User().Email = "pqr@email.com"
```

Using `If`:

```
If(User().Email = "abc@email.com" || User().Email = "xyz@email.com" || User().Email = "pqr@email.com", true, false)
```

Comment: What would the formula look like using "IF" for multiple users?

Comment: check updated answer. let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the formulas. Unfortunately, it only works for me, it doesn’t work for other accounts, I don’t know why yet

Comment: You have to use the correct email addresses and **publish** the app before testing from other accounts.

Comment: Please tell me, should I enter the formula in the column "visible" or "Displaymode"

Comment: `Visible1` property as you want to show/hide based on current logged in user email address.

Comment: It turns out that it is necessary to enter the mail with a small letter and now it works, thanks you. I used the following code: Lower( User().Email) = "123@gmail.com" || Lower(User().Email) = "123@gmail.com